# Excel VBA - Finding a relative range of data

Tags: vba, excel

Bit of a VBA noob so please don't cringe too much at my code. I have a document with rows of data that always changes, and I wrote a small function to clear the previous entries before completing the rest of the macro. My goal is to clear all entries in Column H. I don't want to clear the entire column, just rows 6 and below. This works fine:

```
Range("H6", Range("H1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

I then want to enter my formula that I placed in H6 for each row that has data in the same row in Column A. I paste values over the formula when finished also. I do this as follows:

```
    If Range("A7").Value <> "" Then
        Range("H6").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H6:H" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Range("H6", Range("H1048576").End(xlUp)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
```

The above all works fine. However, my issue is if I insert a column towards the front this breaks due to the absolute references. Searching around the site here showed me that I can find the value of my titles in row 5 as follows:

```
Dim MyRng As Range
Set MyRng = Range("5:5").Find("Column Title", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

But then I'm at a loss on how to do the rest of my code with the MyRng value. I'm guessing my backasswards way of going to the bottom of the sheet and jumping up to the last value to find the data range is the issue.

So once I find the column with the title in row 5, how do I set my range to be all the cells below it with data?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't want to find/set a range. Just find the column number then use `cells` instead of `range`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim MyRng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

With ActiveSheet

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set MyRng = .Range("5:5").Find("Column Title", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    c = MyRng.Column
    Debug.Print c

    If .Range("A7").Value <> "" Then
         .Range("H6").Select
         Selection.AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(6, c), .Cells(lastRow, c))

         .Range("H6", .Range("H1048576").End(xlUp)).Select
         Selection.Copy
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If

End With
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a start that I could try working with, but still a few references to Column H that I want to get relative to MyRng. I think I could do the autofill, but the copy paste values part I'm not sure how to do while only referencing relatively.

Comment: Sigh. I upvoted you because you showed effort but clearly you didn't bother to study my answer :/

Comment: Why be condescending about it? You solved half my problem, I asked for guidance on the other half while i'm trying to work it out on my own. I have now since solved the rest of it and have it working with no absolutely references, but kinda a crap way to respond to a new member, no?

Isn't the point of this for me mark a complete answer (or at least direction to get there), not half an answer? Someone else finds my question and does what you have above, they aren't done.

Comment: @Brad I solved your **entire** problem completely by demonstrating how to use `cells` instead of `range`. I can spoon feed you an answer which I would find far more insulting to your intelligence or I could give you an opportunity to figure it out on your own so you can learn from it (which appears you have). Anyone who finds my answer is done if they care to understand the code.